# cookie not getting deleted in grails

Tags: grails, cookies

I am using

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("dscartorderid","${cart.id}")
                    cookie.maxAge =7*24*60*60*10
                    cookie.setPath("/")
                    response.addCookie(cookie)
```

to create a cookie in one controller and using

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("dscartorderid","")
                    cookie.setMaxAge(0)
                    cookie.setPath("/")
                    response.addCookie(cookie)
```

to delete the cookie. But the cookie is not getting deleted?? I am not able to figure out what is wrong with the code..

Comment: tried cookie.setMaxAge(-1) .but it didnt seem to work..

Comment: cookie.setMaxAge(0) => cookie.maxAge =-1

Comment: in which browser are you testing? Max-age doesn't always work with IE

Comment: I have tried cookie.maxAge=-1 . I am using firefox...It is not working

Comment: You don't show the line in your code but can I assume your next line is `response.addCookie(cookie)`?

Comment: setMaxAge(0) should delete the cookie immediately. setMaxAge(-1) keeps the cookie till the end of the browsing session.

Comment: The code seems to work everywhere else except the after interceptor of login controller provided by spring security...Is there any guide line that cookies cannot be created in login controller??

Comment: I realize that this question is 2 years old, but in the interest of having an answer, I just had a similar issue, and the solution was related to spring security.

The method in the controller has to be annotated with @Secured['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'] otherwise it looks like spring security silently skips the cookie delete method.